# Orchard1.7 - Bootstrap Integration

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

I have used Orchard for my project and installed Bootstrap 3.0.0 theme as it will quick and reliable for me to design whole site using Bootstrap 3.0.0. I have created one custom module using http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor
But at the end, I am not able to get access of my module. Let me know if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootstrap 3 theme on the gallery. You can find it here: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Bootstrap

It's pretty straightforward to modify, it also will help you to build your own theme and understand how the things work.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your reply. I got my solution. I have accessed my modules and integrated easily. But now, on one thing I stucked is when I create new module and enter some content Items its not allowing to enter in to database. The error I am getting is "could not execute query: because of timeout expired. "